# Не отображается изображение как background

Tags: html, css

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Nick Web Studio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="block"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#block {
background-image: url ('/images/nws_head.png');  
}
```

Не отображает картинку. Правильность пути я проверил, background, background-image менял, кавычки `' "` пробовал, без кавычек тоже пробовал, убирать слеш перед путем - тоже пробовал, однако изображение не отображается. В чем проблема?

**Обновление**

Ничего не понял, пробовал и высоту с шириной ставить, не помогло. 
код сейчас выглядит так:

```
#block {
    background-image: url (images/nws_head.png);
    width: 80%;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: @nicksemkin, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: # форматируйте код, 

уважайте других участников

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что было предложено достаточно ответов, однако пользователь не дал никаких уточнений по вопросу и не появлялся с 7 сентября 2013

Answer (score 1):

Первым делом откройте инспектор браузера ( в Chrome *f12* ). 
Если картинка не загружается, то в консоли выведется ошибка ( вкладка *console* ). Если там ошибок нет - идем дальше

Поставьте фиксированные размеры для блока

```
#block {
    /* для теста лучше вообще удалить пока остальные стили */
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(images/nws_head.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Проверьте еще, загружаются ли у вас вообще стили. ( опять же в консоли *f12* )

**P.S.**

> DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

На дворе уже 2015, *HTML5* как год уже стандарт, не бойтесь его использовать

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Блок имеет заданую ширину и высоту (если вдруг у него position: absolute|fixed)?

Сам путь к CSS файлу указан верно? (заметьте, там нет слэша)

**Обновление**

```
div#block{background-image: url("./images/nws_head.png");}
```

Путь к картинке указываем относительно css файла (без ./ тоже можно, но в шапке вопроса вы его задали вообще от корневой директории).

Добавил "div", чтобы парсер не съел, он там необязателен.

Comment: Дочитал, спасибо)

Comment: dekameron, не помогло:(

Answer (score 0):

Сначала делаем так: пробуем из браузера пройти по пути к картинке и посмотреть отображается ли она. Если браузер пишет 403 или 404 значит путь указан неверно или не хватает прав доступа.

Если все гуд, тогда смотрим код и устанавливаем для начала блочный тип элемента не static а именно block устанавливаем высоту и ширину и проверяем отображается ли в блоке, если в блоке не отображается открываем инспектор скажем в хроме или в лисе и смотрим загрузило ли картинку и в консоли смотрим не зачеркнута ли она. Если зачеркнута ищем причину.

Answer (score -1):

```
background: url(../images/foto1.jpg);
```

Надо вот так делать..